# How do I extract all data points from a lowess smoother using R?

Tags: r

I have used the following code to create the graph and a smoother. Now, I am wondering how I can get the data points for the line.

```
plot(mydata$chlindex ~ mydata$Time, pch=mydata$treatment, col=mydata$treatment)

for (i in c(1, 2, 3, 4)){
  lines(lowess(mydata$chl[mydata$treatment==i] ~ mydata$Time[mydata$treatment==i]),
  lty=2, col=i)
}
```

Thanks,
Michelle

Comment: If you change the loop to `tmp[[i]] <- lowess...` and under that have `lines(tmp[[i]], lty = 2, col = i)`, when the loop finishes you will have an object, `tmp`, which has saved all of the lowess objects which contains the x- and y-coordinates of those lines. You will need to create `tmp` before the loop (`tmp <- list()` or something). Also, `lowess` is old, `loess` is the newer version.

Answer (score 1):

**Fabricated data example**

create a couple correlated variables (correlation not necessary, but slightly more fun)

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:200)
df <- within(df, y <- rnorm(200,x*.01))
```

produce a scatter plot with the loess line

```
plot(df)
lines(predict(loess(y~x,df)),col="red")
```

[image]

**Getting the loess line points**

note that `predict()` was used in the drawing of the line. use it without `lines()` to get the points.

```
predict(loess(y~x,df))
#  [1] 0.2461715 0.2498436 0.2536022 0.2574490 0.2613854 0.2654131 0.2695336
#  [8] 0.2737485 0.2780593 0.2824677 0.2869751 0.2915832 ...
```